# Flash JavaScript (Ajax) doesn't work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash, actionscript

I made a Flash application that add's content to a page using JavaScript(Ajax). But strangely enough it doesn't work in IE(7 nor 8). It works fine in Chrome and FireFox.
The JavaScript function is (probably) not the problem, because when I insert `javascript:functionName(id);` in my browser it works.
In my Flash I use the JavaScript on a button with the following code:

```
getURL("javascript:functionName(id);");
```

I suppose that, that's a good way to use it?

But strangely enough nothing works in Flash, not even if I replace the code with `alert('hello my friend');`(maybe he's not my friend?).

Could someone help me out and tell me what may be causing the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using AS [ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to communicate with JS, have a look on this: http://www.nelsond8.com/?p=515#more (here I'm using swfobject built in method **swfobject.getObjectById**, if you are not using swfObject replace this line with **document.getElementById**)

If you are using AS2, you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(id)
{
alert('hello my friend');       
return 'hello my friend';

}
</script>
```

AS2:

```
import flash.external.*;

btn.onPress = function() 
    {
        var jsReply:String = String(ExternalInterface.call("myFunction", "01"));

        getURL("jsReply");

        trace(jsReply);
    }
```

And here is the externalInterface reference page for AS2: http://flash-reference.icod.de/

Comment: @nelsond8; Thanks for replying! I tried reading the ExternalInterface documentation but I don't quite get it. Could you explain it to me? Also I'm using actionscript 2, I don't know if the documentation is only for as3? Thanks.

Comment: @nelsond8; Also my Javascript isn't communicating with the Actionscript, it's the other way around.

Comment: I would also advise you to use swfObject for embedding your swf file

Comment: @nelsond8, the code looks a bit confusing too me. Why would you have an alert() after the return statement in the JavaScript function? Nothing after return will execute, right? And getURL("jsReply") will try to navigate to the URL "jsReply", I don't see what good that would do?

Comment: @Lars, yes you are absolute right about the alert, my mistake. I should have put that before the return. It was just to test the ExternalInterface.call and make sure it was working. About jsReply, it will navigate to whatever string returns from the JS method. My code does not make sense, you are right. It should not be take as a final product, but only a demonstration of how it should work. The question it self does not give you any clue of what it should do, so I just code a method that return a string.

Comment: @nelsond8, I understand that the code is not a final product, but you can still edit your answer if you see errors in it. About getURL("jsReply"), since jsReply is within quotes, it will always be the string "jsReply", regardless of what is returned from the JavaScript, you probably meant to write getURL(jsReply), without the quotes. Maybe the example would be better of without any getURL() call.